# JavaScript event not triggering function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

http://jsfiddle.net/MasterWhipper/88K92/

I'm making a project for school and I decided to use JS which has been good up until the point where I cannot click <kbd>Burma</kbd> from the list of 6 countries. When I do it does not act as the others and change the text below as clicking the other countries does. I've looked for errors but can't find any. Does anyone know whether the JS or the html is wrong?

```
    <td>♦<a onclick="myanmar()">Burma</a>♦</td><td>
```

Is the affected code along with the function `myanmar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally overriding the original myanmar function near the end...

```
function myanmar() {
    document.getElementById("slide").src="myanmar2.png";
}
```

Shoule probably be ...

```
function myanmar2() {
    document.getElementById("slide").src="myanmar2.png";
}
```

Comment: When I get a rep of +15 I will come back and like this thank you so much ;u;